# ReactDOM.render webpack error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

there is this annoying error that I have no idea how it's an error,

I was rendering `MuiThemeProvider` in the react dom like this

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

but webpack is giving me this error:

```
ERROR in ./client/src/app.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (14:2)

  12 | 
  13 | ReactDOM.render(
> 14 |   <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
     |   ^
  15 |     <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  16 |   </MuiThemeProvider>,
  17 | document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

I tried a div instead, didn't work. I tried adding it to const then call it in the render, also didn't work.

I don't understand.

Here is the file code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import { browserHistory, Router } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes.js';

// remove tap delay
injectTapEventPlugin();



ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

Comment: Can you share a test repo with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Webpack is not recognizing your JSX code.  You need to set up webpack to transform JSX.   I use babel to transform my JSX code as follows:

my `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
// ...
    module:  {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env', 'react']
                    }
                }
            }, // ...
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: I recommend gist.github.com instead of imgur for text

Comment: Just as an aside, I recommend using the `exclude` option for babel so it doesn't scan `node_modules` etc. Saves time and problems.

Comment: Yes, it was, but after I restarted the MAC it showed this Syntax error

Comment: To diagnose the problem, try commenting the render code and try a simple html element.  

e.g. https://gist.github.com/lingo/151f5bb1a66a89a0c76c55d3899f5fa4

See if you still get an error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152377/discussion-between-luke-h-and-abdulrahman-mushref).

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [Mui documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/v0.15.0-beta.2/#/get-started/usage) it is handled in that way:

```
const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react-app')
);
```

As far as I know, you aren't able to pass multiple elements into the `ReactDOM.render(renderElement, DOMElement)` function ([React Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html)), so you have to wrap them with a react component without state.